# Rider "External file changes sync might be slow" warning for Unreal Engine 5 Project

Tags: c++, jetbrains-ide, unreal-engine5, jetbrains-rider

I'm getting an error for my project
" **External file changes sync might be slow**
JetBrains Rider cannot receive filesystem event notifications for the project. Is it on a network drive? "
I am using Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon

How can I get rid of this? Did I miss something or should I do something? Is this can cause a problem in feature?